# Alienware laptop monitor stopped working after connecting to an external monitor, Kali Linux OS

Tags: kali-linux, xrandr, multi-monitor, hdmi

Installed Kali Linux on my Alienware M17 laptop;

- laptop monitor was working
- connected to an external monitor via HDMI, configured the external monitor as the primary, laptop monitor as secondary; all were working initially
- used xrandr command to dim laptop monitor; laptop monitor stopped working, while external monitor was working
- If I unplug the external monitor and reboot my laptop, the laptop monitor will display as expected; as soon as connect the external monitor back in HDMI, external monitor will work but the laptop monitor will black out with occasional flickers.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded my video card driver to Nvidia and the problem has been solved, now I am happily running Kali Linux with my laptop monitor and my external monitor.